# Efficient way to check conditions in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a clients model, in the below instance variable i am collecting all the identifiers.

```
@all_clients = Client.all.collect{|a| a.identifier}
```

this returns `["client123", "client234", "client567", "client789"]`

Further, I have a variable @create_id = "client123" and I am checking if the @create_id's value is there in the collection by doing `@all_clients.include? @create_id` 
if returns true I will be appending "_1" to it like this: `@create_id<<"_1"` and saving the `@create_id` later creating a client by that ID.

And again i check if the latest `@create_id` that is "client123_1" is present in the collection and if yes I add _2 and check further and finally save. 
This is as far as I know the worst way of checking anything as I am new to programming.

Can someone help me to find an efficient way to do this.

> All I need to do is to first check the collection if my variable is
>   present if not then append _1 to it and later check if string_1 is
>   already present and move further to _2 or _3 and further. The
>   underscore and the integer keeps increments depending on checking the
>   collection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, client123_4 will be saved into collection ***only*** if client123_1, client123_2, client123_3 are already present? Otherwise consecutive saving might never end.

Comment: Yes exactly. Only when I find that the appended integer with the underscore is not present then I save the  @create_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the AR query to only include records which prefix-match your `@create_id`

```
clients=Client.arel_table
matching_clients = Client.where( clients[:identifier].matches( "#{@create_id}%" ) )
```

If `matching_clients` is empty there is no client with that identifier prefix yet. Otherwise
now you can extract the integer suffix pieces and figure out what the next available id is.

```
last_suffix = matching_clients.
  map(&:identifier).
  map { |s| (s.split('_',2)[1] || 0).to_i }.
  max
```

If the identifier field is supported by an index, this should be fairly efficient.

If your scheme used a suffix format that would allow correct lexical sorting of the suffix (eg, always pad the suffix to a fixed width), then you could push even more of the work into the database with its index by just asking for the greatest identifier which matches.

Be warned this whole approach is subject to race conditions if you have multiple concurrent processes which may want to create a new unique identifier. If your db schema has a unique index on `clients.identifier` (which supports the query efficiency too), then the db will throw a uniqueness constraint error when you try to save a record with the new identifier you manufactured, in which case you can just keep trying by re selecting and deriving the new candidate identifier until you succeed again.

Comment: Thanks man, you nailed it. I got some new ideas to proceed.